# Preventing event propagation to CardActionArea

Tags: material-ui

I have a ClassroomCard component -

```js
<Card
    sx={{ minHeight: 275 }}
>
    <CardActionArea component={Link} to={`${classroom.code}/dashboard`}>
      <CardHeader
        action={
            <CardActions>
                 <ThreeDotMenu options={menuOptions} />
            </CardActions>
        }
        title={classroom.name}
        subheader={`Subject:${classroom.subject}`}
    >
    </CardHeader>

        <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="subtitle2">
                Teacher: {classroom.teacher.name}
            </Typography>
        </CardContent>
    </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

This is what `ThreeDotMenu` looks like -

```js
function ThreeDotMenu() {
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
    }

    return (
            <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
                <MoreVertIcon />
            </IconButton>
            ...
    )
}
```

This is how I want the `ClassroomCard` to look like -

[image]

When I click on the three dots, the menu shows up along with a ripple effect on the card.
And, on clicking on any menu item, the CardActionArea event fires.

How do I prevent the CardActionArea event from running if the ThreeDotMenu is clicked